# open browser from java program with post parameter prefilled

Tags: java, web-applications, browser, post-parameter

I have a java program, where i can open a Internet Explorer or Any Browser.
using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

But I want to open a browser from my java program mentioning url and post parameter.

First of all, is this possible? How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can appled the URL to the command line parameter for example in IE:

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Firefox:

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" stackov
erflow.com
```

and Chrome:

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
" stackoverflow.com
```

Works on windows, you will need to replace `C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` with the the location of the application in your environment

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do about this. Unless the browser you are opening has some available command line arguments (you'd have to look them up, and they would be browser specific), you won't be able to do it.

May I suggest using a Java browser window:

The [SWT Browser](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) object has a fairly large API, and will use a native browser for rendering the pages.

Specifically this snippet will do what you're looking for:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet330.java