# How to open a fresh new browser from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, browser, default

I want to open a fresh browser from my servlet application. Is there any way to do this?

Not.. this is my first browser opening from the application. I am not running this servlet from a browser.

Please send you suggestions.

Comment: *"I want to open a fresh browser.."*  As your hypothetical user, I'd prefer to choose whether to have a new browser window.  Also, please leave sigs. out of questions, they are noise.

Answer (score 2):

**Simply impossible**.Without sending any `request` from the `browser`,you can't send a response to `client`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It is requirement in our application. Because, From Oracle Forms, I want to call a paymetn gateway application. For that, I am creating the URL dynamically and send this to our SSL settuped server. So, in SSL server, we deployed a war file to get the response.

Comment: So without knowing to whom you have to send how will you send ? are my words making sense?

Comment: we are calling a jar file from Oracle forms. from this JAR file, creating the URL and calling the deployed war. the war is deployed in another server. not in the oracle forms server.

Comment: So,where does browser came in between ?

Comment: there is no browser opened till now. I want to open it. so I asked the question. Now we are opening the file from the jar file using Desktop class.

Comment: This might be helpful.You can using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653045/open-browser-from-java-program-with-post-parameter-prefilled

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, You can't open new browser window because its requires Client side permission, Servlet response can only return response in text/html or file format